# Paypal Express checkout NO PRICE

Tags: php, session, scripting, paypal, payment

I've used paypal express checkout sandbox, but When I click to purchase something, doesn't show any price or item name in paypal. 
[image]

On my page I've put this form :

```
<form action='expresscheckout.php' METHOD='POST'>
<input type='image' name='submit' src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif' border='0' align='top' alt='Check out with PayPal'/>
</form>
```

And I've included these two codes from paypal into my scripts:

https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/download.php?file=ecfile

https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/download.php?file=pplibfile

As I said, when I click on pay button , it takes me to the paypal sandbox, but with no price or item name. I even tried this with real API name and pass but still no price.

Meanwhile, I've also manually set the price in the expressscheckout.php :

**`$paymentAmount = $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"];`**

**to**

**`$paymentAmount = 32;`**

Comment: Please share the contents of expresscheckout.php.

Answer (score 0):

For Website Payments Standard :
I have put following two tags in my form tag :

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php print $itemName; ?> "/>
<input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="<?php print $amount; ?>"/>
```

Comment: This is for Website Payments Standard. OP is using Express Checkout.